# In kashering, can you leave utensils eino ben yomo *before* cleaning?

Tags: halacha, time, kashering-kosherization, cleaning

As I understand, the first step in kashering a kitchen is to thoroughly clean everything and then leave it untouched for 24 hours (eino ben yomo).

Would it be technically permissible to clean the appliances/surfaces/utensils *after*, not before, leaving them untouched 24 hours?

Practically speaking, it can be hard to kosher a kitchen while needing to eat from it; there are cases where this alternative could make it much easier. I'm not sure of every reason why it might be allowed, but I do know that any food potentially stuck to the appliances would probably be considered stale after 24 hours (or, in my case, the six months that the clean kitchen has been lying untouched). Stale food is of a different category in many kashrus situations.

So, can I clean everything again and then get right down to kashering? Or must the eino ben yomo strictly be after cleaning?

Comment: Note: the reason I think I need to repeat the cleaning in my case is that the previous cleaning was not done by me, nor done with the intention of rendering things fit for kashering. I *do* need to clean things again, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a Shach who says the food in a kli will prevent the blios from becoming pagum. Therefore cleaning should come first. Assuming the amount of food left is fit for this process. (Let's assume according to the Shach that a miniscule amount will not stop the blios from becoming pagum) The cleaning does not have to be done with any special intentions, one would only need to be able to assume that it is in fact clean.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but I asked a rabbi this question and he said flatly no.

Answer (score 1):

Not all kashering requires 24 hours

when you clean if you do not use somthing that is yad soledet bo (meaning if you do not use hot water) it stays not Ben yomo

But if you do use heat (or as @doubleDD sais if you let liquid sit for 24 hours) then it might become Ben yomo again if there was substance of food there and you will need to wait 24 hours from then

Intention of the cleaning (and even the kashering) does not make any difference (unless you have the intention not to overheat something then it might make a problem (ie if you are torching glass))

Comment: What about Kavush beKeilim?

Comment: @DoubleAA What kavush are you referring to?

Comment: @DoubleAA to wash somthing by keeping if soaking for 24 hours (when it will probably be pogum and boel bshishim)